# I am getting SSL certificate error in linux when making request, but in windows every things is ok

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat8

I am getting this error in Tomcat on Linux when making an HTTPS request to another server.  On Windows, SSL requests work fine.  Could you please help me to resolve this.

I have loaded a keystore inside my app, so no configuration is needed.

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =
    new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(keyStore,
                        new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build(),
        verifier);
```

Error :

```
SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
      PKIX path building failed:
      sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
      unable to find valid certification path
```

Comment: sorry, after deploying and lunching war file under tomact in linux and working with app and sending request to other server with https request by resttemplate, I got that exception. but in windows every things work fine

Comment: Run your application with JVM argument `-Djavax.net.debug=all` that should be very clear about what stores it is loading and what it's trying and failing to do. You could compare the outputs to see the difference between what's working and what's not.

Comment: Which java version are you using for Windows and Linux?

Comment: Windows and linux  1.8.231

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from just the code snippet you've provided.

It could be many things but here is some thoughts:

1. Your certificate does not exist in the keystore you have included in the app
2. Your keystore does not have the indended ceritifcate.
3. You are loading a keystore that is not the one you think you are trying to load, thus it does not have the certificate.
4. The certificate in the keystore is not right.
5. When running it on Windows, you might have set a flag like: -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false which disables the checking.
6. Maybe you have some VM flag that is diverting the correct path for the keystore, like: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=

Run with the VM flag: -Djavax.net.debug=all to potentially see additional data about your keystore.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said it works fine in windows